# Why am I getting errors on the braces?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

The code:

```
public class EmptyTile extends TileEntity{ //error on this brace
    try{
        defaultTexture=TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("stone.png")); //defaultTexture is created in the class that this class extends
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //also an error on this brace
    public EmptyTile(int x, int y, int height, int width, Texture texture) {
        super(x, y, height, width, texture);
    }
}
```

I've also tried moving the try/catch statement to the EmptyTile constructor, but it needs to initialize the default texture before the super constructor gets called, which apparently isn't allowed.

I've also tried making the defaultTexture variable both static and regular in the parent class of this class.

Comment: try using static { try {...

Comment: ya, probably looking for static initializer

Comment: I don't think static is what is wanted: "defaultTexture is created in the class that this class extends". I think it is not static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not put a `try/catch` at the class level, only inside a constructor, a method or an initializer block. That's what's causing the error reported. Try moving the code inside the constructor, assuming that `defaultTexture` is an attribute:

```
public class EmptyTile extends TileEntity {

    public EmptyTile(int x, int y, int height, int width, Texture texture) {
        super(x, y, height, width, texture);
        try {
            defaultTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("stone.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But if `defaultTexture` is an static attribute, then use a static initializer block:

```
public class EmptyTile extends TileEntity {

    static {
        try {
            defaultTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("stone.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public EmptyTile(int x, int y, int height, int width, Texture texture) {
        super(x, y, height, width, texture);
    }

}
```

Comment: _"You can not put a try/catch at the class level"_ That's not necessarily true, you can remove the static keyword in your second example and it becomes an instance initialization block.

Comment: @Radiodef if you read on, it says: "only inside a constructor, a method _or an initializer block_". You're describing an initializer block.

Comment: But by not specifying and not showing an example your answer (apparently accidentally) implies there's only initializer blocks for static.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EmptyTile extends TileEntity{
    public EmptyTile(int x, int y, int height, int width, Texture texture) {
        super(x, y, height, width, texture);
        try{
            defaultTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("stone.png")); //defaultTexture is created in the class that this class extends
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if `TileEntity` uses `defaultTexture` in the constructor, you will have to modify the constructor to allow it to be passed in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it outside the constructor you can put it in an instance initializer block:

```
public class EmptyTile extends TileEntity {

    // empty brace is instance initializer
    {
        try {
            defaultTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("stone.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public EmptyTile(int x, int y, int height, int width, Texture texture) {
        super(x, y, height, width, texture);
    }
}
```